# How to pass Attributes to Custom Dataclass

Tags: python, customization, decorator, class-attributes

I am currently trying to implement a self-written Dataclass wrapper/decorator in python.
I have massive trouble passing the arguments and attributes of the function which i want to use that Decorator on.

My thoughtprocess until now:
The decorator doesnt know how many attributes and argument the class has, but i somehow still have to access them. I then would have to access those via the "**attribute**" names. Since the dataclass decorator mainly does what the **init** does(and optionally **eq** and so on), i would have to pass the classes/instances **dict** to access all args. I have already tried to find it myself in Pythons Language reference in the Data Model, but i couldnt find it.

I would appreciate any kind of help, be it where i find the answer in the docs, some kind of tip or a little code snippet.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it by myself, but this site helped me a lot while learning it by myself: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#decorating-functions-with-arguments

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but you can read the source of the standard library's `dataclasses` module [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py). Maybe that will help?

Comment: Thanks :) i would like to implement my own init method, pythons dataclass contains 1000 lines of code. Im far from being able to write that. So i just wanted to write a decorator that does what the init does in pythons classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataclass` decorator does essentially two steps while creating a default `__init__` instance method for a class:

1. It extracts all class variables using `__annotations__` (See [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations)) attribute of the class, as is documented in the [docstring of dataclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/28d28e053db6b69d91c2dfd579207cd8ccbc39e7/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1032).
2. It creates a `string` containing the entire function definition, with a full parameter list, generated from the class variables of step 1 and if present their default values. It then uses [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) to actually run that as python code, which in turn generates a new `user-defined function object`. That new object is finally assigned to the `__init__` attribute of the decorated `class object`.

So to modify the parameter list of the newly created `__init__` function to match the class variables, `dataclass` creates a new function definition. There seems to be no direct way of modifying the parameter list of a function object outside the function definition itself.

Comment: Thanks, i got it now. You Saved my day.